# Pass cuda texture variable as an argument

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu, textures, cuda-arrays

I have setup the `cudaArray`, and have bound it to a texture:

```
    texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc =
        cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
    cudaArray *cuArray;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocArray(&cuArray,
                                    &channelDesc,
                                    width,
                                    height));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpyToArray(cuArray,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      hData,
                                      size,
                                      cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Now I am wondering, if the content within the `cuArray` and `tex` remains the same all the time during the calculation, can I pass `tex` and/or `cuArray` to another function so that I don't have to do the binding every time?

Something like this:

```
DoJobUsingTex(float* output, float* input, int size, texture tex)
{
   \\  do something here
}
```

Comment: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/

Comment: @talonmies I have not tried it out, but it looks like exactly what I need. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA introduced texture objects when CUDA 5 and Kepler hardware were released. These are so called "bindless" textures which can be passed by value to kernels, so there isn't a need to rebind memory every time  you want to run a kernel on different texture data.

You can read more about their use [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/).

Comment: Should you be interested in read/write capabilities, you may want to look at cuda surface objects.